# How to store local Storage into sql database

Tags: javascript, sql, json, html, local-storage

I have an app working OK for local storage, but I would like to save its data into a SQL database (for instance server = https://myserver.com with user= myuser, password=mypass) using JSON, could you please help me, please find bellow my codes:

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
        <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-stye" content="black">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="img/touch/apple-touch-       icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="img/touch/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="img/touch/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="img/touch/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/touch/apple-touch-icon.png">

        <!-- Tile icon for Win8 (144x144 + tile color) -->
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="img/touch/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#222222">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
        <script src="../js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
 <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>
            <hgroup>
                <h1>iPad Web Application Development</h1>
            </hgroup>
            </header>
            <nav>
            <ul id="tab-bar" class="page-spots">
            <li id="tab-spots">
                <a href="../index.html">Images</a>
            </li>
            <li id="tab-sighting">
                <a href="../video/index.html">Video</a>
            </li>
            <li id="tab-stars">
                <a href="../data/index.html">Database</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
           <h1>Contacts</h1>
<table id="contacts-table">
    <tr id="contacts-head">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Info</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
</table>

<form id="contacts-form"  action="#" method="post" onSubmit="">
    <div class="item text">
        <label>First name:</label>
        <div class="field"><input type="text" name="first_name" required /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item text">
        <label>Last name:</label>
        <div class="field"><input type="text" name="last_name" required/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item text">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <div class="field"><input type="text" name="email" required/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item text">
        <label>Information:</label>
        <div class="field"><textarea rows="7" cols="30" name="information" required></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <div class="item button">
            <div class="field"><input type="button" id="contacts-op-discard" value="Discard" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item button button-default">
            <div class="field"><input type="submit" id="contacts-op-save" value="Save" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id_entry" value="0" />
</form>

            <footer>
                <p>Stereo Vision Web Application &copy; 2014</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <script src="../js/vendor/zepto.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/helper.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/video.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/data.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/server.js"></script>
        <script scr="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script scr="http://html5form.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.html5form-1.5-min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
var Contacts = {
    index: window.localStorage.getItem("Contacts:index"),
    $table: document.getElementById("contacts-table"),
    $form: document.getElementById("contacts-form"),
    $button_save: document.getElementById("contacts-op-save"),
    $button_discard: document.getElementById("contacts-op-discard"),

    init: function() {
        // initialize the storage index
        if (navigator.onLine) {
            //code
            document.body.style.background="white";
        }else{
            document.body.style.background="#c0c0c0";
        }
        if (!Contacts.index) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("Contacts:index", Contacts.index = 1);
        }

        // initialize the form
        Contacts.$form.reset();
        Contacts.$button_discard.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            Contacts.$form.reset();
            Contacts.$form.id_entry.value = 0;
        }, true);
        Contacts.$form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            var entry = {
                id: parseInt(this.id_entry.value),
                first_name: this.first_name.value,
                last_name: this.last_name.value,
                email: this.email.value,
                information: this.information.value
            };
            if (entry.id == 0) { // add
                Contacts.storeAdd(entry);
                Contacts.tableAdd(entry);
            }
            else { // edit
                Contacts.storeEdit(entry);
                Contacts.tableEdit(entry);
            }

            this.reset();
            this.id_entry.value = 0;
            event.preventDefault();
        }, true);


        // initialize the table

         if (window.localStorage.length - 1) {
            var contacts_list = [], i, key;
            for (i = 0; i < window.localStorage.length; i++) {
                key = window.localStorage.key(i);
                if (/Contacts:\d+/.test(key)) {
                    contacts_list.push(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key)));
                }
            }

            if (contacts_list.length) {
                contacts_list
                    .sort(function(a, b) {
                        return a.id < b.id ? -1 : (a.id > b.id ? 1 : 0);
                    })
                    .forEach(Contacts.tableAdd);
            }
        }


        Contacts.$table.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            var op = event.target.getAttribute("data-op");
            if (/edit|remove/.test(op)) {
                var entry = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("Contacts:"+ event.target.getAttribute("data-id")));
                if (op == "edit") {
                    Contacts.$form.first_name.value = entry.first_name;
                    Contacts.$form.last_name.value = entry.last_name;
                    Contacts.$form.email.value = entry.email;
                    Contacts.$form.information.value = entry.information;
                    Contacts.$form.id_entry.value = entry.id;
                }
                else if (op == "remove") {
                    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove "'+ entry.first_name +' '+ entry.last_name +'" from your contacts?')) {
                        Contacts.storeRemove(entry);
                        Contacts.tableRemove(entry);
                    }
                }
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }, true);

    },

    storeAdd: function(entry) {
        entry.id = Contacts.index;
        window.localStorage.setItem("Contacts:"+ entry.id, JSON.stringify(entry));
        window.localStorage.setItem("Contacts:index", ++Contacts.index);
    },

    storeEdit: function(entry) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("Contacts:"+ entry.id, JSON.stringify(entry));
    },

    storeRemove: function(entry) {
        window.localStorage.removeItem("Contacts:"+ entry.id);
    },

    tableAdd: function(entry) {
        var $tr = document.createElement("tr"), $td, key;
        for (key in entry) {
            if (entry.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                $td = document.createElement("td");
                $td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry[key]));
                $tr.appendChild($td);
            }
        }
        $td = document.createElement("td");
        $td.innerHTML = '<a data-op="edit" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Edit</a> | <a data-op="remove" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Remove</a>';
        $tr.appendChild($td);
        $tr.setAttribute("id", "entry-"+ entry.id);
        Contacts.$table.appendChild($tr);
    },

    tableEdit: function(entry) {
        var $tr = document.getElementById("entry-"+ entry.id), $td, key;
        $tr.innerHTML = "";
        for (key in entry) {
            if (entry.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                $td = document.createElement("td");
                $td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry[key]));
                $tr.appendChild($td);
            }
        }
        $td = document.createElement("td");
        $td.innerHTML = '<a data-op="edit" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Edit</a> | <a data-op="remove" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Remove</a>';
        $tr.appendChild($td);
    },

    tableRemove: function(entry) {
        Contacts.$table.removeChild(document.getElementById("entry-"+ entry.id));
    }
};

Contacts.init();
```

Comment: You'll need to make a ajax call to server side code that will in turn communicate with SQL.

Comment: Thanks ElliotM, do you have any tutorial to recommend??

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/ajax/working-with-PHP-and-MySQL.php This is adecent one I've found, but you'll want to look into AJAX, PHP, and SQL separately as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create custom cache mechanism for ajax calls using localStorage in JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899855/how-to-create-custom-cache-mechanism-for-ajax-calls-using-localstorage-in-jquery)

Comment: Is it possible to make this with node.js??

Comment: I am learning node.js now, and I have a similar question. My connection between the database and javascript works very well, but I can't show this at the website in html in tablical view. My html code showing the table, as well as the functionality works too.